# Why is "git branch" silent in new repositories?

Tags: git, git-branch

When you create a new repository and run `git branch`, it exits silently. For example:

```
$ mkdir /tmp/foo; cd /tmp/foo; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/foo/.git/

$ git branch
```

Why doesn't the command provide any output, or show the master branch?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### TL;DR

No branch heads exist yet.

#### Detailed Explanation

A Git repository has no branches until you make your first commit. A newly-initialized repository sets HEAD to refs/heads/master, but refs/heads/master won't exist or contain a commit pointer until after the first commit is made.

During a commit, Git dereferences the symbolic-ref HEAD to find the head of the current branch, and then updates that head with the commit hash supplied by git-commit-tree.

The end result is that `git branch` has nothing to report in a new repository. With no branch heads present, it simply terminates silently with an exit status of zero.

#### See Also

- git-branch(1)
- git-commit-tree(1)
- git-symbolic-ref(1).
- git-update-ref(1)
- gitcore-tutorial(7)

Comment: Nice explanation what is going on in the back. This will help users to understand how git works.

Answer (score 2):

Note that a branch is simply a pointer to a commit.
Since an empty repo (with its [empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765453/gits-semi-secret-empty-tree)) has no commit, you have no branch.

A first commit will create a branch named '`master`', because `HEAD` references `refs/heads/master`.
Should you want to create a first commit on a *different* branch (than `master`), you would need to change the symbolic ref of HEAD first (as detailed in [this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/how-to-start-with-non-master-branch-td3284326.html)):

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/non-master
```

And then make your first commit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you first need to perform

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'first commit'
```

commands.