# 'git branch' does not show the branches names

Tags: github, git-branch

I am using git on ubuntu.

`git branch` does not show the branches' names. I tried cloning different repositories, but again `git branch` does not show the branches' names.
I have also created a new repository and it is the same.

Example:

```
>git clone https://github.com/uber/pyro.git
Cloning into 'pyro'...
remote: Counting objects: 13342, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Total 13342 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 13319
Receiving objects: 100% (13342/13342), 55.85 MiB | 5.34 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (9814/9814), done.
>ls
pyro
>cd pyro
>git branch -a
>git branch -r
>git branch
>git status
On branch dev
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/dev'.
```

Adding another branch:

```
>git checkout -b branch1
Switched to a new branch 'branch1'
>git branch
>
```

I have also committed one time. and it is the same.

```
>GIT_TRACE=1 git branch
15:39:13.295464 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git branch
15:39:13.296121 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: unset 
GIT_PAGER_IN_USE; LESS=FRX LV=-c pager
>git --version
git version 2.17.1
>
>env -i git branch
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
* devress RETURN)
>
```

I have tested the same commands on another laptop and it works. (I have also uninstalled git and reinstalled it. It doesn't help)

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173128/discussion-on-question-by-a-sh-git-branch-does-not-show-the-branches-names).

Comment: Update: I disabled the git pager for the `git branch` by using `git config --global pager.branch false`. Now I can get the results. But as @Keith said, we still don't know why pager cause this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a complete answer, but based on a lengthy chat discussion, it looks like some kind of interaction with the pager.

The user's environment includes these variables (among others):

```
LESSOPEN='| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
LESSCLOSE='/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
```

Those are the default settings on Ubuntu, so that *shouldn't* be causing a problem.

`git branch` produces no output.

`GIT_PAGER=/bin/cat git branch` produces the correct output.

I haven't yet figured out why the pager should be causing this problem, but since changing `GIT_PAGER` to `/bin/cat` is a workaround, that must be what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Show local branches:

```
git branch
```

Since you are cloning from remote/origin branches, it will not displaying using git branch. you need to at least visit that branch by using `git checkout`. Review below git commands. I have created new branch `hotfix-test` and then used `git branch`

```
~/pyro (dev)

    $ git checkout -b hotfix-test
    Switched to a new branch 'hotfix-test'

~/pyro (hotfix-test)

    $ git branch
      dev
    * hotfix-test
```

Checkout the current branch to existing other branch.

```
$ git checkout lax
Switched to a new branch 'lax'
Branch lax set up to track remote branch lax from origin.

~/pyro (lax)
 $ git branch
          dev
          hotfix-test
        * lax
```

Cloning steps and origin branches

```
 ~/desktop (master)
$ git clone https://github.com/uber/pyro.git
Cloning into 'pyro'...
remote: Counting objects: 13342, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Total 13342 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 13319
Receiving objects: 100% (13342/13342), 55.85 MiB | 2.69 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (9814/9814), done.

~/desktop (master)
$ cd pyro

desktop/pyro (dev)
$ git branch -a
* dev
  remotes/origin/0.1.2-release
  remotes/origin/0.2.0-release
  remotes/origin/0.2.1-release
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/dev
  remotes/origin/ast-char-rnn
  remotes/origin/bnn-mnist
  remotes/origin/causal-tutorial
  remotes/origin/continuation-poutine
  remotes/origin/continuation-with-indep
  remotes/origin/cubo
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/dice-elbo
  remotes/origin/gh-pages
  remotes/origin/glom-autoname
  remotes/origin/hmc
  remotes/origin/jit-integration-tests
  remotes/origin/lax
  remotes/origin/lax2
  remotes/origin/maps-iei
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/mvn-sym
  remotes/origin/mvncv
  remotes/origin/nightmare-poutine
  remotes/origin/nips-2017
  remotes/origin/only-continuation-poutine
  remotes/origin/only-parallel-enumeration
  remotes/origin/paul-mh-12-1
  remotes/origin/pcg
  remotes/origin/pragmatics-example
  remotes/origin/ps-semaphore
  remotes/origin/pyro_GP
  remotes/origin/recursion-scope
  remotes/origin/regtest-1
  remotes/origin/rejector-research
  remotes/origin/revert-611-verlet-pr
  remotes/origin/rsa-ccg-example
  remotes/origin/sampling-hash
  remotes/origin/snorkel-example
  remotes/origin/trace-posterior-sample-fix
  remotes/origin/tst
  remotes/origin/vec-rand-module

 ~/desktop/pyro (dev)
$ git branch -r
  origin/0.1.2-release
  origin/0.2.0-release
  origin/0.2.1-release
  origin/HEAD -> origin/dev
  origin/ast-char-rnn
  origin/bnn-mnist
  origin/causal-tutorial
  origin/continuation-poutine
  origin/continuation-with-indep
  origin/cubo
  origin/dev
  origin/dice-elbo
  origin/gh-pages
  origin/glom-autoname
  origin/hmc
  origin/jit-integration-tests
  origin/lax
  origin/lax2
  origin/maps-iei
  origin/master
  origin/mvn-sym
  origin/mvncv
  origin/nightmare-poutine
  origin/nips-2017
  origin/only-continuation-poutine
  origin/only-parallel-enumeration
  origin/paul-mh-12-1
  origin/pcg
  origin/pragmatics-example
  origin/ps-semaphore
  origin/pyro_GP
  origin/recursion-scope
  origin/regtest-1
  origin/rejector-research
  origin/revert-611-verlet-pr
  origin/rsa-ccg-example
  origin/sampling-hash
  origin/snorkel-example
  origin/trace-posterior-sample-fix
  origin/tst
  origin/vec-rand-module
```

See Also
[Why is "git branch" silent in new repositories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077919/why-is-git-branch-silent-in-new-repositories)

Comment: In this case OP is not creating a new repository, he is downloading an existing repository.

Comment: I have also double checked to ensure that the repository is not inside any other one. I re cloned that in another place also. the same thing

Comment: @A_sh please review the above steps.

Comment: please check the question, I have updated that @Nisarg

Comment: Thank you @Nisarg . It is the same. I did that. I have also committed a file and it is still the same. please check the question

Answer (score 0):

I have disabled the git pager for the `git branch` by using `git config --global pager.branch false`. Now I can get the `git branch` output. But we didn't figure out what is the pager problem. For the other commands like `git diff`, the same problem exists.